# I want to change the color of the tick marks on input[range]

Tags: html, css, input

## What I want to know.

I would like to create and customize a slider in HTML.
While various sites explain how to customize the slider itself, I could not find any explanation of how to customize the scale itself.
If I add data using `input="range"`, `datalist`, or `option`, how do I change the color of the ticks added by datalist?

```
      <input
        type="range"
        min=0
        max=100
        step={1}
        list="tickmarks"
      />
      <datalist id="tickmarks">
        {Array.from({ length: max - min + 1 }, (_, i) => i + min).map((label) => (
          <option key={label} value={label}/>
        ))}
      </dataList>
```

[image]

Comment: The code inside the datalist element is javascript, but here is just literal and do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

use `accent-color` that will help to change the color of input type range

```css
input[type='range'] {
accent-color: #f2354e;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, sadly. The user is asking about the ticks underneath the slider, not the colouring of the slider itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate @ParTha answer - you can use`js` to listen the range's value and then color it (using `class`) when value is something.

Snippet:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='range']")[0].addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.value < 50) { this.classList.add('lessThen50');}
    else { this.classList.remove('lessThen50')};
});
```

```css
input[type='range'] {
accent-color: #f2354e;
}
.lessThen50 {
accent-color: #2d1694!important;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that inside the  tag it doesn't have anything but javascript. Try that, maybe?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).